# MySQL - Match(...) Against(...) returns empty array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, full-text-search

I am working on the search feature on my website and would like to improve it a little bit.

My website is a tube website.

I used to work with mysql 'LIKE' statement but realized MATCH() AGAINST() was way more performant.

But I still have a problem with small and partial word.

Let's say there is a title in the video database called: 'Funny video about monkeys - Asia - lol'

There are the different select query with what would be returned (using phpmyadmin to avoid error that would be related by wrong php code)

```
SELECT video.*, MATCH (title) AGAINST ('lol' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance FROM video WHERE active = '1' AND MATCH (title) AGAINST ('lol' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY relevance DESC LIMIT 18
returns
nothing

SELECT video.*, MATCH (title) AGAINST ('monkey' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance FROM video WHERE active = '1' AND MATCH (title) AGAINST ('monkey' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY relevance DESC LIMIT 18
returns 
nothing

SELECT video.*, MATCH (title) AGAINST ('asia' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance FROM video WHERE active = '1' AND MATCH (title) AGAINST ('asia' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY relevance DESC LIMIT 18
returns
the video in the database

SELECT video.*, MATCH (title) AGAINST ('asian monkey' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance FROM video WHERE active = '1' AND MATCH (title) AGAINST ('asian monkey' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY relevance DESC LIMIT 18
returns
nothing
```

So if I am right, the video is returned only if it contains the exact word, and if the word is at least 4 chars.

But the strange thing is that 'ft min word len' is set to 2 so event the query 'lol' should return the video. Also, the query states 'IN BOOLEAN MODE' so I guess it should return even commons words.

As from the partial word like 'monkey' instead of 'monkeys', I have no idea how to go around this as using 'LIKE %...% OR LIKE %...%' won't be a solution because I need to get the relevance.

Well thank you for reading and helping me.

Comment: After you reset `ft_min_word_len` you have to rebuild the index.

Comment: Thank you, this fix the first problem, what about the partial word please?

Comment: For partial words you can use `*`(e.g. 'monk*' to match words starting with 'monk'). You can read about the boolean mode syntax in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Comment: Thank you! If someone can post it as an answer instead of a comment I would accept it.